# No match operators[]

Tags: c++

Heyy Everybody. 
Please have a look at my code my getting some errors that I cannot able to resolve by my self.

DP_Wine_problem.cpp:42:17: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::list' and 'long long int')

if(v[x]>v[s])

```
^
```

DP_Wine_problem.cpp:42:22: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::list' and 'long long int')

if(v[x]>v[s])

^

DP_Wine_problem.cpp:44:26: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::list' and 'long long int')

res+=i*(v[s]);

^

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long int
#define mod 1e9+7

int main()
{

    ll n;
    cin>>n;
    list<ll> v;
    ll j;
    v.push_back(0);
    for(ll i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        cin>>j;
        v.push_back(j);
    }
    ll s=n;
    ll res=0;
    for(ll i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(v[1]>v[s])
        {
            res+=i*v[s];
            v.pop_back();
        }
        else
        {
            res+=i*v[1];
            v.pop_front();
         }
         s--;
     }
     cout<<res<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error messages like `no match for` mean, that either the method or operator isn't there at all, or there is such a method, but with different parameter types.

Looking at [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), you can see, that this is the first case, no `operator[]` for `std::list` can be found.

---

Just in case, `v[1]` is *not* the first element in the list, but `v[0]` is. Also `v[n]` is not the last element.

And if the intention of the code is to calculate the sum of `i * min(first, last)`, you might try using [`std::list::front()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/front) and [`std::list::back()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/back) instead

```
for (long long i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    if (v.front() > v.back()) {
        res += i * v.back();
        v.pop_back();
    } else {
        res += i * v.front();
        v.pop_front();
    }
}
```

---

If you want or must use `operator[]` anyway, I would rather use [`std::deque`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque). This container allows both random access (`operator[]`) and also provides methods `pop_back()` and `pop_front()`.

Comment: You suggest that there are two possibilities for this error, but really it can only be that the method isn't there. If the method is there but with different types, the error will be different: "no conversion between one or more of the argument types". If there are multiple overloads, you could also have an ambiguous overload resolution.

Comment: @MSalters I wasn't sure, so just tested this with g++ 9.2. I got *both* messages, "error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'A' and 'B')", but also "note: no known conversion for argument 1 from 'B' to 'int'". So I guess this might depend on the compiler and the particular circumstances.

Answer (score 2):

`std::list` does not have the random access operator `[]`.

Using a `std::vector<long long>` as the type for `v` is the fix.

If you must use a `list` type and are required to trundle along the list in order to reach the `s`<sup>th</sup> element, then use

```
auto it = v.begin();
std::advance(it, s);
```

to retrieve the element `*it`.